# Fill ComboBoxes from Lists within a List

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to add filters to a list of custom objects in .NET 3.5 SP1.
My objects look like this:

```
public class Message {
  string Filename;
  DateTime Timestamp;
  List<ClassA> A;
  List<ClassB> B;
  // ...
}

public class ClassA {
  string Name;
  // ...
}

public class ClassB {
  string Description;
  // ...
}
```

I have an ObservableCollection holding all my Messages; each Message has 2 or more ClassA's and 0 to n ClassB's. I already set up an ListView to display the messages (sorted via CollectionViewSource).

Now I want to add two ComboBoxes to my UI to allowing filtering of this ListView. Of course they should not contain duplicates, so I only want the distinct ClassA.Names and ClassB.Descriptions of *all* Messages currently displayed in the ListView. Also I want the filter of one ComboBox to also apply to the other one.

The filtering of the ListView is already done and working, but I can't figure out how to populate the ComboBoxes.

Answer (score 0):

this should work, where Messages is your filtered message collection:

```
var distinctNames = 
    (from message in Messages
    from a in message.A
    select a.Name).Distinct();

var distinctDescriptions = 
    (from message in Messages
    from b in message.B
    select b.Description).Distinct();
```

Comment: This works, thank you very much. Much cleaner and more elegent than I ever imagined :)
However, I cannot figure out how to access my filtered CollectionViewSource that represents the messages. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Solved it using CVS.View.OfType<Message>. Thanks again for your post.

Answer (score 0):

If I right understand you want to filter `List<Messages>` collection based on `string` values of the properties of the member collections for type `A` and type `B`.

If so, something like this should work you:

```
var msgs = messagies.Select(ms=>ms).Where(ms=>ms.A.Exists(cla=>cla.Name.StartsWith("NameToSearch") && 
        ms.B.Exists(clb=>clb.Description.StartsWith("DescriptionToSearch"))));
```

Note that here I put **AND** operator in query and `StartsWith` string function. You can substitude them with the functions and operators that more suitable to your needs.

**EDIT:**

Good point is to make them also case insensitive, by using *in this case*, for example,

`StartsWith("DescriptionToSearch",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))`

Comment: This looks pretty nice. Is there a way to do this with an ObservableCollection holding the messages?

Comment: Solved it using CVS.View.OfType<Message>. Thanks again for your post.